# Active directory integration not working properly with winbind and samba

Tags: active-directory, samba, ubuntu-12.04, winbind

I'm trying to get my linux box to use active directory authentication.  I believe I have almost everything setup correctly.  I'm able to issue `wbinfo -g` and `wbinfo -u` and see all the groups and users respectively.

**Brief intro to my setup:**

The username I use on my linux box to do admin things is `nick`.  My active directory username is `nwalke`.  They have two different passwords.  I am able to log in to the box with `nick` and that user's password and I'm also able to login as `nwalke` with `nwalke`'s password.

**The curious bit:**

Upon creating the active directory user's home directory, I run a script that requires root access.  This is to setup some system wide things like a samba share for them.  When I log in as `nwalke`, I enter my `nwalke` password and it succeeds.  I'm then greeted with `[sudo] password for nick:`.  If I enter my `nwalke` password here, it says `Sorry, try again.`.  If I enter `nick`'s password, it says `Sorry, user nick is not allowed to execute scriptname as root`.

If I do `groups` as `nwalke`, I see that magically my user has been given the group `nick`.

Now, I accidentally thought that `nick` had a UID of 100, not 1000.  So originally in my `smb.conf` I had `idmap uid 1000-10000`.  The only thing I can think of, is that I logged in with `nwalke` while that was still set and now I'm just being presented with a UID of 1000 forcing linux to think I'm `nick`.

I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Like I said, I'm fairly certain active directory is communicating with my server properly, but something must not be mapped right on the linux side.

Any thoughts?

Here is my `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
    security = ads
    netbios name = hostname
    realm = COMPANY.COM
    password server = adshost.company.com
    workgroup = COMPANY
    idmap uid = 10000-90000
    idmap gid = 10000-90000
    winbind separator = +
    winbind enum users = no
    winbind enum groups = no
    winbind use default domain = yes
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    client use spnego = yes
    domain master = no
    load printers = no
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes
```

Do I need to bind to a user on the linux box somehow?

Comment: BTW, you marked this as accepted. Did my answer help?  I am slightly curious if you were able to figure out specifically which file the winbind mappings were in.

Comment: I was not.  I must have not been restarting winbind or something.  I figured I'd try restarting one more time, and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a UID overlap.
If `nwalke` and `nick` share the same numeric UID the first nsswitch match will win for things like `id`, `sudo`, `ls`, etc. (and the first match is usually out of the passwd file unless you've changed the order in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` or equivalent).

(logins will work with either name, because login looks up the user by name. Having two users with the same name will cause some interesting chaos though...)

Your local (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`) and remote (NIS, Samba, LDAP, whatever) UIDs/GIDs should not overlap.  Fix that core problem and the rest will resolve itself.

Comment: I have changed the value in my smb.conf to `10,000` and it still feels like `nwalke` is getting paired with `1000`.  How do I resolve that?  Would that be on the NIS side of things or is Linux storing what UID it gave `nwalke` before?

Comment: Linux may be caching the UID (`nscd` or similar evil is a likely culprit, I think Samba/winbindd also does caching too so you may want to restart that service).  A quick check could be done by creating another account with a different username/UID and making sure that works.

Comment: I'll have to try that.  I've rebooted the box after I changed the Samba config for other reasons.  And I haven't installed `nscd` on here.  Weird.

Answer (score 3):

> I have changed the value in my smb.conf to 10,000 and it still feels like nwalke is getting paired with 1000. How do I resolve that?

I can't recall which file it is, and I don't currently have a system to check.

When a user first connects an ID will be assigned, and then it will be stored in one of the Samba databases in `/var/lib/samba/`  Take a look in that folder, it might be obvious which file it is.  You could possibly try stopping Samba, and just moving/deleting all the files there, though you would need to re-join the domain since the machine-account credentials are also stored in one of those databases.